# Connect RCA composite video and output to Android phone

Tags: video

I'm trying to connect an RCA composite video cable to an Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S6, specifically). My use case is this: I have a small camera that transmits composite video for use in FPV mode in RC aircraft. On the video receiver, the output is analogue composite video via an RCA out cable/connector. I want to connect this RCA cable to the Android phone to play the (live) video stream.

I can see various connectors on shopping sites such as these:

https://www.amazon.com.au/ELASO-Adapter-Composite-Converter-AV2HDMI/dp/B0995FXFN1/

But it's not 100% clear to me if these will work as most of these seem to be designed for the opposite use case: people more commonly want to connect their phone to their TV and **OUTPUT** video from their phone to their TV. I want to do the opposite (**INPUT** video into my phone), and it's not clear if these types of devices will support this.

What is the best solution to enable what I want to do? I'd ideally prefer one device/connector rather than chaining multiple adapters together, but I'll do whatever needs to be done as long as I'm certain it will work.

Comment: Android devices usually have no HDMI input so you should look for a AV2USB solution. But if such devices will work on Android (because you can not install drivers on Android) is unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung Galaxy S1 manufactured for Asian market has a built in RCA video out feature using the headphone jack

Comment: Thanks Charles, but as per my question I am looking for a way to get video IN to a Samsung phone via RCA, not a way to get video OUT from the phone.